# Page setup not working with document class report

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to personalise my page setup using `fancyhdr`, but it only works for the document class `book`.

I read the `fancyhdr` documentation and I didn’t find any specific difference between the two document classes, although, as I said, it only works for `book`.

For more details, the line "COSTRUZIONE DI MACCHINE" and the page number appear on the same side every page, while I'm trying to alternate them.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

```
%impostazioni impaginazione
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{COSTRUZIONE DI MACCHINE}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter. \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}

%ridefinizione plain
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

Comment: it would have helped if you had provided an example but use `\documentclass[twoside]{article}`

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the next time. Anyhow it solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between `report` and `book` is that the former uses by default the `oneside` option, while the latter uses `twoside`.

With `oneside` all pages are considered to be right-hand ones (odd numbered, even if the actual page number is even), so specifying `LE` and `RE` is moot. And `fancyhdr` actually tells you so:

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is useless.
(fancyhdr)                Please consider using the `twoside' option on input line 6.


Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is useless.
(fancyhdr)                Please consider using the `twoside' option on input line 7.


Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless.
(fancyhdr)                Please consider using the `twoside' option on input line 12.
```

(line numbers may differ, of course).

Use `book`, it's better because it provides you `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, but is the same as `report` under all respects, except for the default option mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: I wanted to use `report` becuase I didn't want it to leave blank pages between chapters, but at this point I reckon it is better to just use `book` with  `openany`. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @GiacomoRecine `report` leaves a blank page *every other page*. ;-)